# Putting if condition in aspx page, take the condition value from the body

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, html

I want to write a if condition on aspx page. Please help me putting the condition.

```
<head runat="server">
    <% if() 
    { %>
   some html
    <% } %>


</head>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

        <input type="hidden" name="menuId" id="menuId" value="ADDNEWTEMPLATE" /> 
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Under if the i need to check if the value of Menuid = "ADDNEWTEMPLATE" then some html statement has to written. Please let me know what should be the condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
<head runat="server">
<script runat = "server">
      string hiddenValue = document.getElementById('<%= menuId.ClientID %>';
</script>   
<% if( hiddenValue == "ADDNEWTEMPLATE") { %> 
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"> 
<% } else {%> 
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
<% } %>
</head>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
       <input type="hidden" name="menuId" id="menuId" value="ADDNEWTEMPLATE" /> 
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: <% if(document.getElementById('<%= menuId.ClientID %>').value == "ADDNEWTEMPLATE") 
    { %>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
    <% }
     else
     {%>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <%}%>   document.getElementById is not identified, the tag is closed after ClientID %> so elsewhere is it shows error